# Delete sheet if sheet is not on the master criteria

Tags: vba, excel

This macro basically will copy row to other sheet based on criteria on master sheet. If data on the master sheet change, it will update each sheet with the new data. But another problem occur, when user completely delete one of the criteria on the master data, it won't delete sheet corresponding to the criteria that has been deleted.

So...my next scenario is, if user completely delete one of the criteria on master sheet, it also will delete the sheet corresponding to the criteria that has been deleted on the master data and if there is new data, it will update each sheet with that new data

the macro code is like this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim wsAll As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim c As Range, rng As Range, copyRng As Range
    Dim el
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wsAll = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

    With wsAll
        Set rng = .Range("B1:B" & .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

        'get all unique values except header
        For Each c In rng.Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1)
            On Error Resume Next
                col.Add CStr(c.Value), CStr(c.Value)
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next c
        'disable all filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        With rng
            For Each el In col
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=el

                On Error Resume Next
                Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(el)
                On Error GoTo 0
                If wsNew Is Nothing Then
                    Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
                    wsNew.Name = el
                End If

                If WorksheetFunction.CountA(wsNew.Range("A:A")) = 0 Then
                    lastRowNew = 1
                    'if it's new sheet copy with header
                    Set copyRng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                Else
                    lastRowNew = 2
                    Set copyRng = .Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                   ' Set copyRng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                End If

                wsNew.Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
                copyRng.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=wsNew.Range("A" & lastRowNew)

                Set wsNew = Nothing
            Next
        End With

        'disable all filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    wsAll.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @simoco thanks for edited, i have connection ploblem here, so the formating bar is'n show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sub DistributeRows()
    Dim wsAll As Worksheet
    Dim wsCrit As Worksheet
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastRowCrit As Long
    Dim lastRowNew As Long
    Dim I As Long

    Set wsAll = Worksheets("Data") ' change All to the name of the worksheet the existing   data is on

    LastRow = wsAll.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set wsCrit = Worksheets.Add

    ' column A has the criteria eg project ref
    wsAll.Range("C1:C" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=wsCrit.Range("A1"), Unique:=True

    LastRowCrit = wsCrit.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For I = 2 To LastRowCrit
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsCrit.Range("A2").Value)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If wsNew Is Nothing Then
            Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
            wsNew.Name = wsCrit.Range("A2").Value
        End If
        lastRowNew = wsNew.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        wsAll.Rows("1:" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=wsCrit.Range("A1:A2"), _
            CopyToRange:=wsNew.Range("A" & lastRowNew), Unique:=False
        wsCrit.Rows(2).Delete
        Set wsNew = Nothing
    Next I

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wsCrit.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

**UPD:**

Here is also another approach using `Collection`:

```
Sub test()
    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim wsAll As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim c As Range, rng As Range, copyRng As Range
    Dim el
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wsAll = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

    With wsAll
        Set rng = .Range("B1:B" & .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

        'get all unique values except header
        For Each c In rng.Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1)
            On Error Resume Next
                col.Add CStr(c.Value), CStr(c.Value)
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next c
        'disable all filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        With rng
            For Each el In col
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=el

                On Error Resume Next
                Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(el)
                On Error GoTo 0
                If wsNew Is Nothing Then
                    Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
                    wsNew.Name = el
                End If
                Set copyRng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

                wsNew.Cells.ClearContents
                copyRng.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=wsNew.Range("A1")

                '***************************************
                'For pasting only values use this one
                'copyRng.EntireRow.Copy
                'wsNew.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                '***************************************

                Set wsNew = Nothing
            Next
        End With

        'disable all filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    'delete sheets
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each wsNew In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If wsNew.Name <> wsAll.Name Then
            If IsError(Application.Match(wsNew.Name, wsAll.Range("B:B"), 0)) Then                   
               wsNew.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next wsNew
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True        

    wsAll.Select

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: i tried your code, but unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: I got "the extract range has a missing or invalid field name"

Comment: after End If and lastRowNew, so it start from wsAll.Rows("1:" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=wsCrit.Range("A1:A2"), _
            CopyToRange:=wsNew.Range("A" & lastRowNew), Unique:=False

Comment: here's the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwQbOGkGl4jwSXNiNU9VQnNDVEE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: updated download link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwQbOGkGl4jwSXNiNU9VQnNDVEE/edit?usp=sharing

also sended to your mail w/ worksheet subject

Comment: @marmalade, I've no issue with my code. Here is test workbook: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wh23a66nq92o9p0/test.xlsm - just run the macro

Comment: @marmalade, see my updated answer - I also added new approach for you - I think it's even better

Comment: It's work perfectly, thanks for your code. There is one problem, when user insert new data to sheet 'Data' and run the macro, it isn't append the newest data, it's append all data, so we have duplicate data on each new sheet. I've trying to modify the code, so when user input new data and run the macro, what I the macro want to do is, clear all row except first row (header) and than paste data to the sheet

Comment: my code modification to the macro is successful, I'll posted it here, but now come another problem. As you know that the macro will create new sheet based on the criteria on the 'Data' sheet. How if user completely delete one of the criteria and run the macro? as we know, the macro will not delete the sheet that doesn't exist in the criteria on the 'Data' sheet. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can loop throught each sheet and if, say, headers in any sheet are the same as headers in sheet "Data", but there is no cells in column `C` (sheet "Data") with sheet name - then delete it.

Comment: I'm trying to use this code to delete the sheet but I still figure it out how to merge with the current code. Here is the code: Dim i As Long, x, wsAct As Worksheet
Set wsAct = ActiveSheet
For i = Sheets.Count To 1 Step -1
If Not Sheets(i) Is wsAct Then
x = Application.Match(Sheets(i).Name, wsAct.Range("B1:B" & .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))
If IsError(x) Then
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets(i).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
End If
Next

Comment: I've updated my code. Btw, in test workbook you send me there are formulas in column `G`. In that case maybe it would be better to paste values instead formulas? You can see how to do it in my code (I've commented this part)

Comment: Thanks very much, It works perfectly! 
Thanks for your help, code, and your kind manner
I really appreciate that.....